# List an utility function's values

Tags: elementary-set-theory, utility

$S$ is a finite set, and $v: S \to\mathbb N$ is a valuation function.

We have $$S := \{0,1,2\}$$

and the valuation function $v$

$$v: S \to\mathbb N\\ k \mapsto 2k+1$$

The task is to list all values for $v$'s utility function $u$:
$$u:\mathcal P(S)\to\mathbb N\\ X\mapsto\sum_{x\in X} v(x)$$

How would I go on about doing so? We weren't introduced to the concept of valuation and utility functions yet, and the internet hasn't exactly helped me at all so far.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if you're looking for an algorithmic approach but, if so, I think you should specify it.

Comment: "Valuation theory" is something different, has to do with fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the tasks seems rather straight-forward to me, I fear I'm missing something crucial in your question. Nevertheless, this is how I'd do it.

Reading the definitions, you must list $v(X)$ as $X$ ranges among the subsets $S$:

1. Pick a subset $X$ of $\{0,1,2\}$.
2. Calculate $u(X)=v(k_1)+\cdots+ v(k_h)=(2k_1+1)+\cdots+(2k_h+1)$, where $k_1,\cdots, k_h$ are the elements of $X$
3. Write down the number you got and restart from step 1 with a subset you haven't already considered.

For instance, let's do one go

1. We pick, say, $X=\{0,2\}$
2. $u(\{0,2\})=(2\cdot 0+1)+(2\cdot 2+1)=6$
3. Add $6$ to our list of values

And the rest are similar. Recall that $S$ has exactly $8$ subsets, one of which is $\emptyset$.